# Is there a way to run a python script in a new terminal window using a perl Script?

Tags: python, perl, unix, terminal

I am writing a perl script, Is there a way to run a python program in a new terminal window from the perl script  and then supply regular inputs in the new terminal  through the perl script ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659226/run-a-python-script-in-perl

Comment: @CoryKramer I want the python script to run in a new terminal window other than the one where the perl script is running.

Comment: @CoryKramer: That question doesn't seem to address the *in a new terminal window* requirement, which I think is the only obscure part

Comment: Which Unix are you using?

Comment: Is the terminal window under a Linux GUI like Gnome?  If so, you need a Gnome command to create a new terminal window.  Please clarify which GUI system you are using - they are all different.

Comment: @cdarke Yes, it's a GUI and I am using Gnome.
I also want to supply several inputs to the python script which is running in new terminal from the perl script that is running in previously opened terminal that is hosting the perl script and that triggered the new terminal.

Comment: Try something like `gnome-terminal -x sh -c python file.py`

Comment: Okay I think you should edit your question to include all this information, as it has changed substantially. We shouldn't really have to ply you with all these questions

Comment: By "inputs", do you mean that the python program is reading `stdin`?  It would be simpler to run the python using a pipe, but that is going to be difficult if it is in another window, unless you can use a named pipe.

Comment: @cdarke, Yes!, the python script is using raw_input.
If it is the same terminal as well it is fine as long as I can give inputs from the perl script

Answer (score 0):

Given your last comment ("*If it is the same terminal as well it is fine as long as I can give inputs from the perl script*") ...

Have a look at [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect).